# Buenas, me gustaria saber si existe en PHP o Java Script una rutina que me permita detectar si una aplicación externa esta abierta

Tags: php, javascript, html

me gustaria saber si existe en PHP o Java Script una rutina que me permita detectar si una aplicación externa esta abierta.

Ejemplo: Que me muestre en mi sitio web construido con PHP o Java Script si se ha iniciado una app externa como Work o Excel?.

Comment: por favor revisa [ask] y de paso realiza el [tour] sería interesante saber que haz tratado o investigado por tu cuenta, ya que del modo que preguntas recibirás poca atención al no mostrar el mas mínimo intento previo

Comment: Y aclara los conceptos, porque si mezclas tan alegremente PHP con Javascript probablemente no tengas claro donde se ejecuta cada cosa...

Comment: Bueno lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente tengo una pagina Index.php donde tengo que cargar una lista de las aplicaciones ejecutada dentro del sistema operativo windows a pesar de que he indagado e investigado en toda parte, no encuentro una rutina (ya sea en php o java script) que se adapte a lo que se debe obtener como resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes hacer eso si estás ejecutando PHP en tu computadora.
El comando `exec` de php te permite ejecutar comandos del sistema operativo y obtener la salida en una variable.

En windows podes ejecutar el comando tasklist y luego parsear las líneas de resultado obtenidas en el segundo parámetro de la función.

```
$salida = array();
exec('tasklist', $salida);
print_r($salida);
```

[PHP exec](http://php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php)

Comment: Nuevamente, responder preguntas que están realizadas sin seguir lo definido en [ask] provoca que el sitio tenga contenido de baja calidad, ayúdanos a orientar al OP a crear preguntas de buena calidad que sean útiles para toda la comunidad.

Comment: @Jorgesys Para elevar la calidad primero, como moderador, no podés meterte en persecuciones individuales cuando un usuario te cuestiona algo. Segundo, podes descalificar una respuesta que no contesta una pregunta o que podría ser un comentario, pero no porque la pregunta es deficiente. En todo caso alguien puede determinar que es deficiente y otro que no. Y aunque la pregunta finalmente se cierre por concenso de que no es adecuada,  no deberías castigar al que contesto considerándola una pregunta válida y contestable.

Comment: Revisar [help].

Comment: @jorgesys Ya lo leí y no veo nada que diga que alguien no debe responder una pregunta por ser deficiente. A lo sumo dice que no hay obligación de hacerlo. Y tiene sentido. Lo que no tiene sentido es bajar linea para que no se contesten preguntas en un sito que es basicamente de preguntas. No hace falta que me contestes, solamente pensalo.

Comment: No se impide preguntar o responder incorrectamente, solo ayúdanos a orientar a los OP a crear preguntas de buena calidad que sean útiles para toda la comunidad no únicamente para el que pregunta.